# glGetError() doesn't work until next frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, glkit

I'm trying to debug this rendering loop that I didn't write. There's an error somewhere that makes the program to crash, but `glGetError()` seems to be acting funny.

This in on *iOS*, and I'm using `GLKViewController`, `GLKView` and `EAGLContext` to draw.

A much summarized version of the render loop is something like this:

```
- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
   // At this point, GLKView's EAGLContext should be the active context

   checkGlGetError();

   if (!isTextureInit || geometryChanged)
   {
        setupRenderTextureAndRenderbuffer();
   } 
    glGetIntegerv(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING, &_originalFramebufferId);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, _framebufferId);

    // a. Some complex operations
    // b. Some rendering on the texture framebuffer

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, _originalFramebufferId);

    // c. Some additional complex operations
    // d. Render the texture on screen

    checkGlGetError();
}
```

This makes the app crash. The problem is that the last `checkGlGetError()` call of the first rendered frame, doesn't produce any error (and nothing shows on the screen).

The first `checkGlGetError()` call of the second rendered frame gives a cryptic `GL_INVALID_ENUM`, and shortly thereafter the app crashes.

If I replace my render loop by this:

```
- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    checkGlGetError();

    // a. Some complex operations
    // b. Some rendering on the screen

    checkGlGetError();
}
```

Everything works, and no errors are reported. But: why doesn't `glGetError()` catches the error immediately after the erroneous OpenGL call? Why does it only report it at the start of the next frame?

The code with the error is quite long, and without any more indications of where exactly the error is, it's being quite difficult to debug.

---

*UPDATE*

I uploaded all the code [here](https://github.com/rsanchezsaez/CardboardVR-iOS/tree/develop). It's a work-in-progress port of [Google's CardboardSDK](https://developers.google.com/cardboard/android/) ([decompiled](https://github.com/raasun/cardboard)) from Java to Objective-C++ that I'm trying to complete.

The main render loop is on the `CardboardViewController` class. The OpenGL command causing the crash should be on the `DistortionRenderer` class (whose function is to take the plain stereoscopic viewports and render them on a texture, in order to apply the lens distortion to each).

If you set `CardboardViewController`'s `distortionCorrectionEnabled` to `NO`, the crash goes away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not enough info in here to debug your problem, so instead, a general note about debugging...

`glGetError` is a poor way to debug GL issues in general, but especially in iOS, and even more so when you're using `GLKView` or other systems that do GL work on your behalf. Quite possibly you're setting some state that doesn't lead to an error until `GLKView` starts committing stuff to the GPU (when your `drawRect:`/`glkView:drawInRect:` returns).

Try using the [Xcode Frame Capture tool](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/ToolsOverview/ToolsOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-A2-SW7) instead. Instead of requiring you to paste `glGetError` checks all over your code (and make sure they're disabled in release builds) and then try to make sense of the results, it shows you the errors (with at least some level of explanation) for each call, including those made on your behalf in system code. And it shows the complete state graph, and snapshots of the frame being rendered call by call, so you can tell earlier if you're setting some state that's causing a problem.

---

Okay, one thought that might be specific to your problem: try using `bindDrawable` on the `GLKView` instead of directly re-binding its framebuffer with `glBindFramebuffer`.

Comment: Thanks, this is supremely helpful. I think I'll be able to debug it myself using *Xcode Frame Capture* tool. Nevertheless, just while you were answering I just added the source code and more details to the question.

Comment: Using bindDrawable fixed one problem related to the depth buffer not being present. But weirdly, now the OpenGL frame says there are invalid enum errors in both of these two lines: `glGetIntegerv(GL_CULL_FACE, &this->cullFaceEnabled); glGetIntegerv(GL_SCISSOR_TEST, &this->scissorTestEnabled);`. According to OpenGL documentation, they seem like valid. Any thoughts?

Comment: Ok, I see now that for those two you are supposed to use `glIsEnabled()` instead (maybe `glGetIntegerv()` works for those two arguments on Android but no on iOS). Trying to fix an additional problem now.